# How can I export .csv files correctly?

Tags: ms-access, export

I've got two tables (8/~150 columns). The first one gets filled with personal data, while the second one is a "checklist" which is filled with one character.

I created a query, which concatenates both tables, to export it as a .csv file. When I try to do so (with the export wizard) I get this exception:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'filename.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path correctly.

I double checked, tried to do it with VBA, but nothing worked.

I don't know what I should try to do.

I'm hoping that someone can help me

Paul

Comment: Oh and if I create a file named like the one I want to export and where I want to export it, it just gets deleted, when I try to export my query

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code ...

Comment: I cannot replicate the export wizard issue.

Comment: try saving the query for your two tables.  then export the data from the saved query using the external data tab and save the resulting export query.  then in vba call DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "YourSavedExportName" and deal with any issues.

Comment: I can't save with the external data tab either... I get the same error

Comment: I can't share the code, because its company related. But it realy is just 2 Tables connected with the employee-ID (primary key) and some Forms, which make the data input easier

Comment: You can share the code if it's really just that simple - no one cares about names of tables or fields. if there's password fields blank them out

Comment: I found a "workaround-solution". I export the query to an Excel file and transform this into an .csv. Im trying to automate this process with powershell or power automate.